# Finding the Cube Root of a Polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Question: Let $P = 27+108x+90x^2-80x^3-60x^4+48x^5-8x^6$, find $\sqrt[3]{P}$.

Just wondering if there is a general way for dealing with this sort of question, I was able to figure how to find $\sqrt{P}$, but $\sqrt[3]{P}$ is beyond me. Long division is used in an example, unfortunately it lacks justification.

Comment: I think a procedure is given in some 19th century algebra textbooks, but I don't have time now to look. Freely available .pdf files of the books I'm thinking of are linked in [this recent math stackexchange post of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358604/how-to-expand-a-0a-1xa-2x2-a-nxn2/358753#358753), in the paragraph that begins with *In older advanced "school level" algebra texts from the 1800s ...*

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro: yes, the above example is from a Hall/Knight algebra book; some really good explanations in your thread there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hope is that $\sqrt[3]{P}$ is also a polynomial. If $\sqrt[3]{P}$ were to be a polynomial, then $\sqrt[3]{P}$ should be of the form
$$\sqrt[3]{P} = (-2x^2 + ax + 3)$$ since the coefficient of $x^6$ is $-8$ and the constant term is $27$. Can you take this further?

Comment: Yes, $\sqrt[3]{P}$ is also a polynomial. Just can't figure out how it is done.

Comment: @Orpheus What are your thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: yep it's needed to compare coefficients, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(3+ax-2x^2)^3=27+108x+90x^2-80x^3-60x^4+48x^5-8x^6$

Now use  [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Example) and compare the coefficients of the different powers of $x$ to find the unique value of $a$  such that all the equation formed  by comparing the coefficients remain consistent.

Comment: It should suffice to look at just, say, the $x^5$ terms, with possibly the linear terms as a check, since they require the fewest permutations in multiplying out the cube of the putative cube-root polynomial.  The $x^5$ can only be formed from three sets of $(-2x^2)(-2x^2)(ax)$ and the linear terms from three sets of $3 \cdot 3 \cdot ax$.  If those _don't_ produce the same value of $a$, our polynomial won't serve as a cube root of $P$.