# General expanded form of $(x+y+z)^k$

Tags: algorithms

(hope it doesn't seem so weird),
I'm looking for a general expanded form of
$(x+y+z)^k, k\in\mathbb{N}$.

$k=1: x+y+z$

$k=2: x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2xz+2yz$

$k=3: x^3+y^3+z^3+3xy^2+3xz^2+3yz^2+3x^2y+3x^2z+3y^2z+6xyz$

$k=4: x^4+y^4+z^4+4xy^3+4x^3y+4xz^3+4x^3z+4yz^3
+4y^3z+6x^2y^2+6y^2z^2+6x^2z^2+12x^2yz+12xy^2z+12xyz^2$

The elements are obviously determined by combinations of their powers, whose sum is always $k$. 
I just cannot find the algorithm for element's constants

Comment: Related: [How to expand $(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...a_nx^n)^2$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358604/how-to-expand-a-0a-1xa-2x2-a-nxn2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that just as you can use Pascal's Triangle for binomials, you can use [Pascal's Pyramid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_pyramid) for trinomials. Otherwise, you can use the Multinomial Theorem as Jp McCarthy suggested

[image: Pascals' Pyramid]

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $(x+y+z)^k \equiv[\color{red}x+\color{green}{(y+z)}]^k$.

Now use the binomial formula for $(\color{red}a+\color{green}b)^k$.

Comment: For the specific question, I much prefer this answer to mine.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy http://imgur.com/iOFLp

Answer (score 4):

It is the [Multinomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).