# Confusing Symbol - Plane Trigonometry Book

Tags: trigonometry, summation

I am currently reviewing a book titled "A Treatise in Plane Trigonometry" by Hobson that was written in $1891$ and it does not  always explain use of symbols.

The author shows two trig identities (I want to prove these)

$$\tag 1 \sum \sin 2A \sin^2 (B+C) - \sin 2A \sin 2 B \sin 2C = 2 \sin(B+C) \sin(C+A) \sin(A+B) \\  \sum \cos 2A \cos^2 (B+C) - \cos 2A \cos 2 B \cos 2C = 2 \cos(B+C) \cos(C+A) \cos(A+B)$$

He then states that these two identities are based on the  algebraic identity

$$\tag 2 \sum 2a (b+c)^2 -8abc = 2(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)$$

In both cases, I do not understand how he is using the $\sum$ symbol. Is it only applying to the first item on the LHS or both terms?

I have tried a few permutations on $(2)$, but am still not seeing it and it is probably something simple.

Can anyone shed light on how to properly read and derive $(2)$?

Comment: I just saw this question, and while it's already been answered, you might find the application of this sigma notation near the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/358753/13130) of interest.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Thanks + 1 - By the way, I always enjoy reading the book lists you write - especially the way older books!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In both cases, I do not understand how he is using the $\sum$ symbol. Is it only applying to the first item on the LHS or both terms?

First item, only, $\sum x + y$ is usually understood to mean $(\sum x) + y \ne \sum (x+y)\,$.

> $$\sum 2a (b+c)^2 -8abc = 2(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)$$

The LHS is a cyclical sum, often written as $\sum_{cyc}\,$:

$$\sum_{cyc} 2a (b+c)^2 -8abc = 2a(b+c)^2+2b(c+a)^2+2c(a+b)^2 - 8abc$$

> Can anyone shed light on how to [...] derive (2) ?

You can simply expand, collect and cancel terms on both sides. Or, for a shortcut, note that the LHS is $0$ for $a=-b$, so (considered as a polynomial in $a$) it must have a factor of $(a+b)$. By symmetry, it must also have factors of $(b+c)$ and $(c+a)\,$, then what's left must be a constant (by degree considerations). Finally, take for example $a=b=c=1$ to figure out the constant factor of $2$.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I should have realized that! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that $\sum$ is used for circular sum, that is: $$\sum2a(b+c)^2=2a(b+c)^2+2b(a+c)^2+2c(a+b)^2.$$
At least, the claimed algebraic identity is true using this interpretation.