# Topological Equivalence of Norms

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Proposition: 
Prove that $d,d'$ generate the same topology on M if and only if $\forall x \in M$ and $\forall r>0$ $\exists$ $r_1,r_2$ such that $B^{d'}(x,r_1)$ $\subseteq$ $B^{d}(x,r)$ and $B^{d}(x,r_2)$ $\subseteq$ $B^{d'}(x,r)$.

I was able to prove the above proposition.
The problem I want to solve is the following:

Define a metric $d'$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $d'(x,y)=$ $max_{i=1,2...,n}$ $\{$ $|x_i-y_i |$ $\}$. Show that the euclidean metric and $d'$ generate the same topology.

I know that for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $|x_i-y_i|$ $\leq$ $||x-y||$, consequently $max|x_i-y_i|$ $\leq$ ||x-y||,.

Now, I'm trying to find an $r_1>0$ so that $B^{d'}(x,r)$ $\subseteq$ $B^{d}(x,r)$ where $r>0$ is arbitrary.

May I have some hints which is something other than the equivalence of the metrics, as I know (and was able to prove) the equivalence of the metrics, please?

Comment: Hint: $\|x-y\|_{max} \leq \|x-y\|_{eucl} \leq \sqrt{n}\|x-y\|_{max}$.

Comment: [Relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2267519/4280) IMHO. For both parts. $d_\infty$ is your $d'$ etc. and the Euclidean metric is $d_2$ there.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the inequality: $$|x_j|\le\sqrt{\sum_{1\le j\le n}^nx_j
^2}\le\sqrt{n}\max_{1\le j\le n}|x_j|.$$ May be try to prove it first and, then apply for you problem appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

$ΗΙΝΤ$

In $\Bbb{R}^d,$ the open ball centered at $x$, with respect to the maximum metric is an $n-$ dimensional cube  centered at $x$ and with edge width $2r$