# Equivalence of metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, uniform-spaces

**Definition 1.**  Two metrics $d_{1}$, $d_{2}$ on a set $X$ are equivalent, if there exist two positive numbers $c$, $c'\in\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$, such that if $x$, $y\in X$ then$$
c d_{2}(x, y)\leq d_{1}(x, y)\leq c'd_{2}(x, y).
$$

**Question.** What does the equivalence of metrics mean? I think there are some types of equivalence:

1. $d_{1} = d_{2}$ i.e. $d_{1}(x, y) = d_{2}(x, y)$ for all $x$, $y\in X$.
2. The induced topological structure with respect to $d_{1}$ is equal to that of $d_{2}$.
3. The induced uniform structure with respect to $d_{1}$ is equal to that of $d_{2}$.
4. The induced "structure of metric space" with respect to $d_{1}$ is equal to that of $d_{2}$, although I don't know what it means.

I tried to show 2, but it seems to be false. As for 3, I don't know enough about uniform spaces. If 4 is true, does the definition 1 defines the equivalence of "structure of metric space", or is there a clearer definition ?

Comment: Why do you think 2 is false? Did you find any counterexample where such equivalent metrics give different open sets? However if you meant whether the definition is equivalent to 2, then indeed 2 should be weaker.

Comment: Oh is it true? I have no idea to show 2. implies Def. 1.

Comment: I see, so you are trying to establish equivalence rather than implication. See [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics) for some explanations: Def. 1 is the 'strong equivalence,' while 2 is the 'topological equivalence.'

Comment: @K.Y.: (2) does not imply Def’n. 1: it is weaker than Def’n. 1.

Comment: Thanks. Then, is the following true? : In theory of metric spaces, a metric space is a equivalent class of a pair of set and its metric, with respect to def 1. Also, all definitions about metric spaces (for example, totally boundedness) should be well-defined up to the equivalence.

Comment: What I stated above is false, because it won't work in defining isometry. Is there standard name for the equivalence stated in Def. 1?

Comment: What you have is usually referred to as "Lipschitz equivalence" (in honour of [Rudolf Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolf_Lipschitz)), because the identity $(X,d_1)\to (X,d_2)$ (and back) are Lipschitz continuous functions.  Note that it is stronger than preservation of uniform structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 is certainly true, as I explain in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2267519/4280), but more can be said: having this "equivalence via constants", it's quite clear that the uniformities induced by $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the same: for every entourage of the form $\{(x,y) \mid d_1(x,y) < r\}$ we can find another entourage of the form $\{(x,y)\mid d_2(x,y) < r'\}$ that is a subset of it and vice versa, and as these kinds form a (filter) base for the respective uniformities from $d_1$ resp. $d_2$, we get that the uniformities are the same.

So $d_1$ and $d_2$ induce the same *uniform* properties: uniform continuity, total boundedness and Cauchy-ness and completeness means exactly the same under either.

3 alwyas implies 2 as well, but 3 is stronger and so probably the intended answer, as 4 is false:

If a map is an isometry wrt $d_1$ it need not be an isometry w.r.t. $d_2$ or vice versa. So really *metric* stucture (where the actual values of the metric matter!) can be different. We can alraedy see this by the "shapes" of the balls under the different equivalent metrics on $\Bbb R^2$. Ths shows that point 4 is false.

So the most informative is 3: the uniform structure is the same (and hence the topologies too).